# Excel Formula to find 1st matching result, 2nd matching result, etc

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of employees on one sheet and an export of customer verbatim comments on another. I am attempting to get a formula to work where it is able to pull the first comment for each agent and then in the next column it would pull the 2nd comment for that agent, then 3rd, and so on.

Here is a simplified example - [Sample File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vq7shiHdwWWoOL1crnrOZUuJhlv1mV4t/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105192158476707530780&rtpof=true&sd=true). I've tried the formulas below...

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$11,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!A2=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$11,ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$11)-ROW(Sheet2!$A$2)+1),1)),"")


=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$11,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!A3=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$11,ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$B$11)-ROW(Sheet2!A3)+1),2))
```

But the ROW functions seem to be the wrong ones for what I need. It's giving me the feedback for the next row down, not the feedback for the next row matching the agent name.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I would use `Filter` to get all the comments then either `Transpose`, `WrapRow` or `toCol` to get all comments into row format

Answer (score 0):

*This solves the issue:*

**Caveat**

- *This command/method only will work with Excel Version 2021 and higher (365).*

---

[image]

---

- Formula in cell N2: `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($S$2:$S$8,$R$2:$R$8=M2,""))`
- Adjust cell references as needed.
- `TRANSPOSE` with `FILTER` has been used because, output are in
  Horizontal order.